# Will my android service be able to access a singleton object defined in my app

Tags: android, android-intent, service, kotlin

I have a `GlobalData` singleton `object` in my app. I want to add an android service to it. Will `GlobalData` (which is a kotlin `object`) be accessible from the service after the app is destroyed?

More generally which parts of an app are accessible to an android service after the app is destroyed?

Comment: the global data is global to application if application is dead/destroyed it means the data is null for sure.

Comment: @Anmol What about shared preferences? Will they be available?

Comment: shared preferences also die when application is dead. explain your use case in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will GlobalData (which is a kotlin object) be accessible from the service after the app is destroyed?

No, If app is not alive, your data will be also cleared. Instead please save your data into a persistent storage like [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) so that you can retrieve your last saved data when your application gets again alive.